# Unix partial string comparison

Tags: unix

I need to compare a string partially to check for a given condition.
Like my $1 will be checked if it has a part of a string BLR
while my file input has $1 entries as BLR21 BLR64 IND23
I only need a true condition when $1 is equal to BLR**
where these stars can be anything.
I used a simple if condition

```
if($1=="BLR21")
{print $2}
```

Now this only works when whole BLR21 is there in row.
I need to ckeck not for BLR21 but only BLR.
Please Help

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not great, I hope I understood.

## Quick and easy solution

```
grep BLR input.txt
```

This will output all the lines in which "BLR" is found, in file input.txt.  It will match "BLR" with any prefix and suffix, whatever they might be (spaces, alphanumerical, tabs, ...).

## "Complicated" solution

A bit more complicated.  It does the same thing, but makes sure input.txt exists, and is in the form of a script.

Input file, input.txt:

```
BLR21 BLR64 IND23
```

Your script could be:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Arguments
inputfile="input.txt"

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]
then
    echo "Usage: myscript.bash <STRING>"
    exit 1
else
    string="$1"
fi

# Validation, and processing...
if [[ ! -f "$inputfile" ]]
then
    echo "ERROR: file >>$inputfile<< does not exist."
    exit 2
else
    grep "$string" "$inputfile"
fi
```

And to call the script, you do:

```
./myscript.bash BLR
```

But really, a simple `grep` does the job here.

## Taking it even further...

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Arguments
inputfile="input.txt"

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]
then
    echo "Usage: check.bash <STRING>"
    exit 1
else
    string="$1"
fi

# Validation, and processing...
if [[ ! -f "$inputfile" ]]
then
    echo "ERROR: file >>$inputfile<< does not exist."
    exit 2
else
    while read -r line
    do
        if [[ "$line" =~ $string ]]
        then
            echo "$line"
        fi
    done <"$inputfile"
fi
```

Now this one is like going to the moon via mars...
It reads each line of the file, one by one.  Then it checks if that line contains the string, using the `=~` operator inside the `if`.

But this is crazy, when a simple `grep` would do.